# Loading all jQuery Variables on Doc Ready with PJax in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pjax

I have searched this forum and the internet for an answer to this but i can't seem to find the correct solution/I don't understand it entirely...

I had previously setup a rails application to present a simple slideshow. In this I use jQuery to show the next 'slide' by moving the container. I then decided to implement pxax to only load the yield rather than the full page. All of this works fine except my jQuery. I saw that if you add the on() delegate that the event fires again, however my initial variables for things like window = $(window) and div = $(div) no longer work.

```
$(function() {

var presentation_carousel = $('.carousel')
var carousel_width = $(".slide").length * 700;
var carousel_max_next = ((carousel_width - 700) * -1);

var view_window = $(window);
var nav_collapse = $('div.nav-collapse');

presentation_carousel.css('width', carousel_width+"px")

$('.button_next').on ('click', function(e) {
    $('.button').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 100)
    presentation_carousel.animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-=700px"
    }, 500, function(){
        $('.button').css('display', 'block');
        $('#quiz_carousel .button_next').css('display', 'none');

        $('.button').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500)
    })
});
```

Specifically the dynamic resizing of the presentation_carousel div no longer is fired. I also saw that if I add a standard console.log inside the document ready tags it is no longer fired?

It'd be nice if someone could explain how pjax works with standard jQuery and also if someone could help me out with my code?

I did get it all working by not using the variables inside of my functions and crossing the dom every time instead.This however this felt a little hacky... e.g.

```
presentation_carousel.animate({}) 
// became
$('.carousel').animate({})
```

Any help or advice on this is more than welcome. I am new to Rails and am always open to suggestions on drying out and improving my jQuery.

Thank you

Edit: 
Exert from application.html.erb in Layouts. This is the only place the yield is called and it is within the main container div.

```
<div class="span9">
  <div data-pjax-container>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to analyze this code without some demo pages. Is the carousel inside or outside the main content of the page (which gets updated by pjax)? jquery-pjax fires a few events which may be useful - pjax:start, pjax:end and more.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately my boss doesn't want the demo page putting up on the internet. This is the same mark-up style for mine http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-carousel.html

Comment: Would the [jquery-pjax events](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events) be sufficient? `$(document).on("pjax:end", handler)` is roughly equivalent to `$(document).ready(handler)`. Naturally, you still need the ready handler for the initial page load.

Comment: Hi I will give it a go. I must admit I am having trouble finding good documentation explaining the different events that pjax offers. Is there a page that explains it all in a similar fashion to the way the jQuery documentation does? Thanks for your time on this Sean

Comment: The link in my last comment is the only one I know of.

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks for your help. That all worked just fine. I think it as just getting my hear around something other than the .ready() stuff. If you wanna post what you said as an answer below then I will accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in [jquery-pjax events](http://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events) might be sufficient. `$(document).on("pjax:end", handler)` is roughly equivalent to `$(document).ready(handler)`. Naturally, you still need the ready handler for the initial page load. ;)